# Make a navigation drop down show above another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my sub-menu to appear above my body div when hovering over menu. [Here is a picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtkcJ.jpg) since the website is not live yet.

I have been messing around with this for a while now and can't seem to figure out what I have to do to get it to work. I have a z-index value for my sub menu but it still won't show. How can I get the menu to show above the body div?

```css
   

 @charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
 width:100%;
}

/*
 Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
 ----------------------------------
 dw-num-cols-mobile:  4;
 dw-num-cols-tablet:  8;
 dw-num-cols-desktop: 12;
 dw-gutter-percentage: 25;
 
 Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
 http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design
 
 and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
 http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

.fluid {
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

.clearfix:after 
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.menu 
{
    width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 0px;
 top: 0;
}
 
.menu li 
{
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
 font-size: 0px;
}
 
.menu a 
{
    transition: all linear 0.15s;
 font-size: 28px;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .arrow 
{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 0%;
}

.menu > ul > li 
{
    float :left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 19px;
}
 
.menu > ul > li > a 
{
    padding: 10px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a 
{
    color: blue;
}

.sub-menu 
{
    width: 350px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu 
{
    opacity: 1;
}
 
.sub-menu li a 
{
    padding: 10px 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: black;
 background-color: red;
}
 
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a 
{
    color: blue;
 
}

.sub-menu ul li :hover ul
{
 
}

.gridContainer 
{
 width: 88.5%;
 max-width: 1232px;
 padding-left: 0.75%;
 padding-right: 0.75%;
 margin: auto;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.zeroMargin_desktop 
{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_desktop 
{
    display: none;
}

#body
{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: black;
}

#container
{
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-right-style: solid;
 border-left-style: solid;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #00008B;
 border-bottom-color: #00008B;
 border-right-color: #00008B;
 border-left-color: #00008B;
 width: 968px;
 background: #FFF;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#header
{
 background-color: #EBC79E;
 width: auto;
 position: relative; 
 height: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#logo 
{
 width: 350px;
 margin:auto;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

#logo h1 
{
 font-size: 55px;
}

#logo h1 a
{
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
} 

#footer
{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #EBC79E;
 position:relative;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #000;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#footer p
{
 padding-left: 35px;
}

#homeBody
{
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #000;
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: -20px;
 background-color: #FFF; 
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 background-color: #CDCDB4;
 position: relative;
}

#homeBody h1
{
 text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;  
}

#homeBody h2
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#homeBody p
{
 padding-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
}

#homeBody img
{
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 display: block; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#87CEFA">

  <div id="container">

    <div id="header">

      <div id="logo">
        <h1> <a href="index.html">New Eve Inc.</a></h1>
      </div>
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a><br>
                <a href="aboutNewEve.html">About</a><br>
                <a href="bagSealing.html">Bag Sealing</a><br>
                <a href="clubPackaging.html">Club Packaging</a><br>
                <a href="displays.html">Displays</a><br>
                <a href="wareDist.html">Warehousing & Distribution</a><br>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="homeBody">
      <h1>New Eve Inc.</h1>
      <h2>Your Partner in Fulfillment Every Step of the Way</h2>
      <p>New Eve has the knowledge and expertise to provide you with the most cost-effective packaging, warehousing, and frieght solutions for your product. We understand that your product is unique, with its own market identity, packaging needs, and delivery
        requirements. This is why we offer solutions that will bring your product to market quickly and more profitably.
      </p>
      <img src="images/high view.jpg" alt="Building">
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p> New Eve Inc. <br> 100 Enterprise Drive Carbondale PA, 18407</p>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. The code you provided doesn't replicate the problem in your screenshot. Please give us a [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Comment: i guess its an z-index issue, give your menu li and menu more z-index than another elements, it will work fine!

Comment: I tried adding z-index to menu li and menu and nothing happens. I also got rid of the z-index I already had in sub menu and it still won't work :(

Comment: I added a Complete example that should replicate the problem now

Comment: z-index would only work if the elements are siblings

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden` from `.container` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: visible` in `#header`

```css
   

 @charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
 width:100%;
}

/*
 Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
 ----------------------------------
 dw-num-cols-mobile:  4;
 dw-num-cols-tablet:  8;
 dw-num-cols-desktop: 12;
 dw-gutter-percentage: 25;
 
 Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
 http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design
 
 and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
 http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

.fluid {
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

.clearfix:after 
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.menu 
{
    width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 0px;
 top: 0;
}
 
.menu li 
{
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
 font-size: 0px;
}
 
.menu a 
{
    transition: all linear 0.15s;
 font-size: 28px;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .arrow 
{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 0%;
}

.menu > ul > li 
{
    float :left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 19px;
}
 
.menu > ul > li > a 
{
    padding: 10px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a 
{
    color: blue;
}

.sub-menu 
{
    width: 350px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu 
{
    opacity: 1;
}
 
.sub-menu li a 
{
    padding: 10px 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: black;
 background-color: red;
}
 
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a 
{
    color: blue;
 
}

.sub-menu ul li :hover ul
{
 
}

.gridContainer 
{
 width: 88.5%;
 max-width: 1232px;
 padding-left: 0.75%;
 padding-right: 0.75%;
 margin: auto;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.zeroMargin_desktop 
{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_desktop 
{
    display: none;
}

#body
{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: black;
}

#container
{
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-right-style: solid;
 border-left-style: solid;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #00008B;
 border-bottom-color: #00008B;
 border-right-color: #00008B;
 border-left-color: #00008B;
 width: 968px;
 background: #FFF;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#header
{
 background-color: #EBC79E;
 width: auto;
 position: relative; 
 height: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 0px;
 overflow: visible;
}

#logo 
{
 width: 350px;
 margin:auto;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

#logo h1 
{
 font-size: 55px;
}

#logo h1 a
{
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
} 

#footer
{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #EBC79E;
 position:relative;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #000;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#footer p
{
 padding-left: 35px;
}

#homeBody
{
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #000;
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: -20px;
 background-color: #FFF; 
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 background-color: #CDCDB4;
 position: relative;
}

#homeBody h1
{
 text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;  
}

#homeBody h2
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#homeBody p
{
 padding-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
}

#homeBody img
{
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 display: block; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#87CEFA">

  <div id="container">

    <div id="header">

      <div id="logo">
        <h1> <a href="index.html">New Eve Inc.</a></h1>
      </div>
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a><br>
                <a href="aboutNewEve.html">About</a><br>
                <a href="bagSealing.html">Bag Sealing</a><br>
                <a href="clubPackaging.html">Club Packaging</a><br>
                <a href="displays.html">Displays</a><br>
                <a href="wareDist.html">Warehousing & Distribution</a><br>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="homeBody">
      <h1>New Eve Inc.</h1>
      <h2>Your Partner in Fulfillment Every Step of the Way</h2>
      <p>New Eve has the knowledge and expertise to provide you with the most cost-effective packaging, warehousing, and frieght solutions for your product. We understand that your product is unique, with its own market identity, packaging needs, and delivery
        requirements. This is why we offer solutions that will bring your product to market quickly and more profitably.
      </p>
      <img src="images/high view.jpg" alt="Building">
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p> New Eve Inc. <br> 100 Enterprise Drive Carbondale PA, 18407</p>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you very much for helping me out

Comment: Glad i could help :). please accept the answer if it indeed solved your problem.